# SitesApp.getActivePage() always return landing page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I use the following function:

```
function doGet(e) {
    Logger.log( SitesApp.getActivePage().getName())
}
```

**It always returns the name of the home page**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with Google currently. All Google Sites are facing this issue. Please submit a bug report, and cross your fingers it'll be solved soon.

[Here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/sites/fyrqtr_RL6A;context-place=topicsearchin/sites/category$3Areport-a-problem%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false) is an existent bug report of this issue. Please +1 it to give it more attention.

Answer (score 0):

There is an older discussion about this issue here [Apps Script .getActivePage() only returning "home" page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754013/apps-script-getactivepage-only-returning-home-page)

which suggests the problem can be related to using setHtmlContent() when the embedded html gets modified. There has been a recent problem with htmlbox on Google Sites for which a fix is in the process of rolling out which may have some bearing on this issue

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have the same issue. My script worked on Old Google Site, but it doesn't work anymore on a new Google Site.
And the issue in this code:

```
var pageUrl = SitesApp.getActivePage().getUrl();
```

My question is almost the same: How to get URL of the current page on the New Google Site with GAS?

[google.script.url.getLocation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/url)

```
google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
  console.log("locations:----------------------------------------");
  console.log(location);
  console.log(location.parameters);
  console.log(location.hash);
  console.log("----------------------------------------");
});
```

The code above gives the next output:
[image]